# Can't find a Perl script from PHP/Apache

Tags: php, apache, perl, system, passthru

From a PHP script I want to run a Perl script. I can do this fine from the terminal (as root user) but when run from my application (www-data user) I can't.

When developing the application on localhost I was able to do this fine as well, but the problem appeared when I switched to another server.

My webpage calls the PHP script with an AJAX POST request, which works fine for my other PHP scripts that do not make calls to Perl.

I have tried the following commands in my PHP script with no success:

```
system("/filepath/file.pl");
exec("/filepath/file.pl");
passthru("/filepath/file.pl");
```

The Apache logs on the server hosting my application show the following error:

```
sh: /file.pl: not found
```

From running the following code on my server I see that the web user is seen as www-data:

```
ps aux | grep apache
```

To test, I have also set the permissions for all files and directories use by my application to allow any type of access by any user, using chmod 777.

Please note: my application is only available to certain users (I use a .htaccess file to set these permissions and require the user to login) so if there is a way to change how the server sees this user (from www-data, to the credentials of the logged-in user) then perhaps that would help - how would I do this?

Comment: `/filepath` would start the ROOT of your drive's filesystem, e.g. ``c:\``. if `/filepath` is the root of your website, well, that won't work. you need to include the entire path: `/home/user/sites/example.com/public_html/filepath/file.pl`- type thing

Comment: Does `'not  found'` really indicate a permissions problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
exec("/usr/bin/perl /full-path/script.pl",$output);
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions! In the end, it was a problem with security settings in the php.ini file in the Apache directory on the server hosting my application:

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Safe mode was set to 'on', which was preventing php files to access/execute any local files. (The PHP script was also failing when attempting access to another, not-script, file: other.html).

To solve this without removing the safe mode setting for all applications on my server, I changed the above php.ini file to include the following:

```
safe_mode: on
safe_mode_include_dir: /filepath
safe_mode_exec_dir: /filepath
```

More information on these config variables can be found here: 
http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php